# Magento compare sidebar move left to right

Tags: magento, sidebar

i have removed default sidebar from category pages , now i just want to show compare sidebar  on right side with products details page right side bar  how can i change this layout to a custom block

will appreciate any Help Thank you

Comment: give more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the template to

> 2-column-right.phtml

Effect -:

It will show the content region in the lefthand side

on the right hand side it will show the compare product,recently reviewed,recently added to cart,etc.

> NOTE:If you want to do some customization it can be done in  page.xml
>   or layout.xml as well

Answer (score -1):

If you change slidebar then you also need to change in css file, according to your size and layout.